# Add columns to ogr2ogr command

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I got code to densify my shapefile but my output got empty columns. How to add to ogr2ogr command request to save input columns to output file in following code?

```
target.write('ogr2ogr.exe -f "esri shapefile" -dialect sqlite -sql "select DissolvePoints(ST_Segmentize(%s.geometry, 1)) as geometry from %s" "%s\\sample.shp" "%s" -explodecollections \n' % (name, name, setupPath, shpin))
```

I tried to add to sql expression SELECT * , but it doesn't work.

Comment: How about `select DissolvePoints(ST_Segmentize(%s.geometry, 1)) as geometry, %s.* ...` May give problems because the original geometry is also picked. Perhaps you need to select the columns explicitly `%s.attribute_1, &s.attribute_2...`

Comment: Your first method adding , %s.* after geometry call works straight ahead. Please add you comment as an answer so i could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you confirmed, in your case it is enough to select also all the other columns from the source layer with "*". The SQL part is then

> "select DissolvePoints(ST_Segmentize(%s.geometry, 1)) as geometry,
>   %s.* from %s"

and your full code

```
target.write('ogr2ogr.exe -f "esri shapefile" -dialect sqlite -sql "select DissolvePoints(ST_Segmentize(%s.geometry, 1)) as geometry, %s.* from %s" "%s\\sample.shp" "%s" -explodecollections \n' % (name, name, setupPath, shpin))
```

I am rather sure that this solution does not generally work because "select *" selects also the original geometry which means that SQL is returning **two** geometries which may even be different datatypes. The GDAL shapefile driver probably just skips the second geometry. The safe way that means a little bit more writhing is to select all the attributes explicitly:

> "select DissolvePoints(ST_Segmentize(%s.geometry, 1)) as geometry,
>   %s.attribute_1, %s.attribute_2, %s.attribute_3 from %s"